# MVC - change control buttons names automatically on VIEWS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

On MVC web projects can we change automatically the control buttons names that are automatically generated on VIEWS? I know that we can change one by one manually, but if we need to create the controller again they get the same standard english name, and i need to change to other languages.
Any tips?
See the example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMdME.png) !
Thanks

Comment: You want to change the value of the name attribute on your HTML form inputs? Why? Who is going to be seeing those?

Comment: It would be helpful to post some code of what you're trying to do

Comment: I need to translate the "edit, details and delete" controls that you can see on the example image. And i need this because not everyone understands english, so, i want to translate that to other languages, to be more "user friendly"...

Comment: @kurdtpage this is just a learning project, i started learning MVC a few days ago and my former/teacher asked us to search about that.

Comment: Create one resource file per language. There are samples on line. In addition you can route the url by language. See http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-using-resource-files-to-manage-string-constants/ and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1160340/Get-insight-to-build-your-first-Multi-Language-ASP If you want something more basic, you can pass a text from the controller to the view by using ViewBag or a property of the model. That way, the text of links, button, etc, will change depending on the language.

Comment: @derloopkat i saw something called "globalization and localization" on the second link that you've posted that might be what im looking for. I will give it a try... Really thanks